# How to get all contents from a webpage as text in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to bring into vba the data displayed under the -Dividend Summary- title of this webpage:
https://seekingalpha.com/symbol/ABBV/dividends/scorecard

By running this line of code in the Google Chrome console I managed to get the info, so I am trying to replicate this in VBA.

```
document.querySelectorAll("div [data-test-id='dynamic-tooltips-area']")[1].innerText
```

The VBA code I have written is this:

```
Public Sub Stackoverflow_Question()

Dim sResponse As String, i As Long, Html As New HTMLDocument
Dim oSelectors As MSHTML.IHTMLDOMChildrenCollection 'Object

'Get response from webpage
With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", "https://seekingalpha.com/symbol/ABBV/dividends/scorecard", False
    .send
    sResponse = .responseText
End With

'Write and read HTML
With Html
    .body.innerHTML = sResponse
    Set oSelectors = .querySelectorAll("div [data-test-id='dynamic-tooltips-area']")
End With

'Print obtained data -this produces no result-
'I loop only to be sure that I don't request the wrong index
For i = 0 To oSelectors.Length - 1
    Debug.Print oSelectors(i).innerText
Next i

'Auxiliary: Create txt with response text
Dim FilePath As String
Dim TextFile As Integer
FilePath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\HTML_ResponseText.txt"
TextFile = FreeFile
Open FilePath For Output As TextFile
Print #TextFile, sResponse
Close TextFile

End Sub
```

Not only do I get no result from the `debug.print`, but a simple search in the `responseText` string shows that contents from the webpage such as the header "Div Yield (FWD)" or the values (4.99% as of today) are not there.

Why is the .ResponseText not working as I expect?

Is there and alternative way to retrieve the webpage content as text?

Thank you in advance

Comment: A simple GET request using XMLHTTP only gets the single resource: if you open that same page in a browser it will make about 140 requests to load the full page.  So your response may contain only partial content.  Many (most?) pages these days require browser automation if you want the full content.

Comment: Anything useful here? https://seekingalpha.com/instablog/753641-david-trainer/5450481-all-members-of-site-get-excel-add-in-and-api  or https://rapidapi.com/apidojo/api/seeking-alpha

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Tim Williams, loading a webpage usually takes more than one request.
In Google Chrome, pressing F12 and going to the "Network" tab shows all of them, as well as their respective Request URL's.
Looking for the wanted one looks like a trial and error task, but it all seems to be there.
In my case, the URL I was interested in is:
[https://seekingalpha.com/api/v3/symbol_data?fields[]=divYieldFwd&fields[]=divRate&fields[]=payoutRatio&fields[]=divGrowRate5&fields[]=dividendGrowth&fields[]=divDistribution&fields[]=dividends&slugs=ABBV](https://seekingalpha.com/api/v3/symbol_data?fields%5B%5D=divYieldFwd&fields%5B%5D=divRate&fields%5B%5D=payoutRatio&fields%5B%5D=divGrowRate5&fields%5B%5D=dividendGrowth&fields%5B%5D=divDistribution&fields%5B%5D=dividends&slugs=ABBV)